Is there a constructive proof of the 4 axiom in $\sf Grz$?
Willem Blok managed to prove that the 4 axiom of modal logic
$\Box \phi \to \Box \Box \phi$
is provable in $K+ \Box (\Box(\phi \to \Box \phi) \to \phi) \to \phi$.
Let $\psi=(\phi \land (\Box \phi \to \Box \Box \phi))$. Blok managed to prove 4 by using the theorem of system $K$
$\Box (\phi \to (\Box (\psi \to \Box \psi) \to \psi))$,
which by propositional reasoning and the K and Grz axioms, implies both 4 and T at the same time.
The only way I could prove the system K theorem was by following Blok’s proof, which uses the classical modal equivalence $\Box (A \to B) \equiv \neg \Diamond (A \land \neg B)$.
Is the theorem of K that Blok used otherwise constructive? The only way I could see to modify Blok’s proof without using $\Box (A \to B) \equiv \neg \Diamond (A \land \neg B)$ requires Pierce’s Law.
